# Django cron is not running using crontab

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cron

I have made a file named `updatefield.py`  content is

```
from FrontEnd.views import UpdateField

def my_scheduler():
    # add logic
    UpdateField()
```

I have put it inside my project root with manage.py file

And my settings.py file is like

```
CRONJOBS = [
('* * * * *', 'Ravi.updatefield.my_scheduler')
]


Installed apps

 'django_cron',
 'django_crontab',
```

After executing command  `python manage.py crontab add`  I got

```
adding cronjob: (33083f0c14f7cccdc5851431976adcbb) -> ('* * * * *', 'Ravi.updatefield.my_scheduler')
```

But its not running Right now . And noting is appearing on my terminal my function is this

```
def UpdateField(request):
    print('hi')
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

Comment: "nothing is appearing in my terminal"—why would you expect anything to appear in your terminal? Cron runs asynchronously. What operating system are you using? Why are you returning an `HttpResponse`? Cron doesn't send an HTTP request.

Comment: @Chris  Print command should not print in terminal ?  I am just testing my real logic is not this . Its just to verify that will this function will run . And its not running . Am I missing some step ?  or have I misplaced my file ?

Comment: Not to the terminal you're looking at, no. It would run in a separate shell and (probably) since it generates output it would leave a message in your local user's mailbox. Again, what operating system are you using?

Comment: @Chris   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS  . And then how to verify as I have set to run my command after every 1 minute?

Comment: and for now I am testing on local machine

Comment: A good start would be to have your task actually do something and check to see that it's being done. Another option is to check your local mailbox with the `mail` command or similar. As I said, cron jobs that generate output usually drop a mail in the local mailbox.